# Use gcc to get all functions from *.c/*.h-file

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a some argument to tell `gcc` just to return all functions given in a c/h-file.

so e.g. `gcc xyz.c -functionnames`
should give:

- `uint8_t abc(uint8_t number)`
- `uint8_t efg(uint8_t number)`
- ...

Comment: No, you can use doxygen for that.

Comment: could you elaborate? i searched for that but didn't find the appropiate command line + arguments for that purpose

Comment: You need a config file for doxygen and then just use EXTRACT_ALL=yes. Just look up some examples on how to use doxygen.

Comment: i already have set up my doxygen and it works...but i wanted to use this output in another program and for that purpose html output is not good/nicely to use

Comment: Well, if you could elaborate on your purpose, maybe I could help you. Doxygen can also generate xml, where you can get the function names from. Alternatively you can use nm on the binary, but then you loose the function signature and only have the names.